# What does 오지다 mean?

Tags: written

I saw it in an article, and I couldn't figure it out. When I searched online (google translate) it says 'come to a bad place' which doesn't make sense. Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this around too! It means something is very good, be it about appearance, attitude or even to mock someone with sarcasm (Oh, you're *so cool*). It can be used negatively or positively depending on the context. Nowadays I've mostly seen it used negatively/in a sarcastic manner.

Other forms:
오지다, 오졌다 , 오진다

It can mean: awesome, cool, amazing, very good, incredible, next-level
Sample sentence:

니 얼굴 정말 오진다 - Your face is really good (looking)

When spoken, it actually sounds like 'O.G.' which is also used in English as 'Original Gangster'.  Who is the real OG?! You are!

Comment: The example given may sound rather sarcastic, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

That is a Korean slang and probably wouldn't be on Google translate. 오지다 means it's very good. 오지다, 오진다 they all mean the same.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, it is a "standard" word in the [dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/c9d2f5d156d240018b92944a98b86161).